# Hibernate exchange unique fields

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints, unique

I have a table containing 2 unique columns e.g:

unique_1 | unique_2

A        | 1

B        | 2

I would like to import a file into my database, but it could contain the field values exchanged:

unique_1 | unique_2

A        | 2

B        | 1

I am using Hibernate and getting org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException. The objects in the table have childrens referring to them - therefore I cannot delete the objects and replace them with new ones - I need an update. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really understand your problem....

Comment: You've shown us the same two tables.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste mistake... edited

Comment: I don't think Hibernate should have anything to do with this.  Just write an update script to first add the new parents, then point the children to those new parents.  Given this, you might want to tell us which database you are using.

Comment: I have to save both entities in the same session. The database consistency remains but hibernate does not know this when it wants to update the first line in the database. So it tries to update the A object but it is going to end up in a unique constraint violation because the B objects unique_2 field is set to the same value.
I am using oracle database.
I need to set the unique constraint to be ckecked only at a commit at runtime and then reset.

Comment: Can you handle this from a SQL script or must it be done from Hibernate?

Comment: It must be done from Hibernate. Is it possible?